# Highcharts Vector Plot with connected vectors of absolute length

Tags: highcharts

Scenario: I need to draw a plot that has a background image. Based on the information on that image there have to be multiple origins (let's call them 'targets') that can move over time. The movements of these targets will have to be indicated by arrows/vectors where the first vector originates at the location of the target, the second vector originates where the previous vector ended and so on.

The result should look similar to this:

[Plot with targets and movement vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoQZ2.png)

While trying to implement this, i stumbled upon different questions:

1. I would use a chart with combined series: a Scatter plot to add the targets at exact x/y locations and a vector plot to insert the vectors. Would this be a correct way?
2. Since i want to set each vectors starting point to exact x/y coordinates i use `rotationOrigin: 'start'`. When i now change `vectorLength` to something other than 20 the vector is still shifted by 10 pixels (http://jsfiddle.net/Chop_Suey/cx35ptrh/) this looks like a bug to me. Can it be fixed or is there a workaround?
3. When i define a vector it looks like `[x, y, length, direction]`. But `length` is a relative unit that is calculated with some magic relative to the longest vector which is 20 (pixels) by default or whatever i set `vectorLength` to. Thus, the vectors are not connected and the space between them changes depending on plot size axes min/max). I actually want to corellate the length with the plot axis (which might be tricky since the x-axis and y-axis might have different scales). A workaround could be to add a redraw event and recalculate the vectors on every resize and set the `vectorLength` to the currently longest vector (which again can be calculated to correlate to the axes). This is very cumbersome and i would prefer to be able to set the vectors somehow like `[x1, y1, x2, y2]` where (x1/y2) denotes the starting- and (x2/y2) the ending-point of the vector. Is this possible somehow? any recommendations?
4. Since the background image is not just a decoration but relevant for the displayed data to make sense it should change when i zoom in. Is it possible to 'lock' the background image to the original plot min/max so that when i zoom in, the background image is also zoomed (image quality does not matter)?

Comment: "Locking" a background image to your chart's actions is going to be tricky and imprecise when the chart is viewed in different browser sizes (Highcharts is natively responsive). Can you share an example of what you'd like to use and how it's used in context with your vectors?

Comment: Let's assume i monitor car axles. In this case i want to see how they move and be able to zoom in to see the movement in more detail. See example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42pHS.png does this clear things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Combining these two series shoudn't be problematic at all, and that will be the correct way, but it is necessary to change the prototype functions a bit for that the vectors will draw in a different way. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/6vkjspoc/
2. There is probably the bug in this module and we will report it as new issue as soon as it is possible. However, we made the workaround (or fix) for that and now it's working well, what you can notice in example above.
3. Vector length is currently calculated using scale, namely - if `vectorLength` value is equal to `100` (for example), and vector series has two points which looks like that:

   ```
   {
     type: 'vector',
     vectorLength: 100,
     rotationOrigin: 'start',
       data: [
         [1, 50000, 1, 120],
         [1, 50000, 2, -120]
       ]
   }
   ```

   Then the highest `length` of all points is taken and basing on it the scale is calculated for each point, so first one `length` is equal to 50, because the algorithm is `point.length / lengthMax`, what you can deduce from the code below:

   ```
     H.seriesTypes.vector.prototype.arrow = function(point) {
       var path,
       fraction = point.length / this.lengthMax,
       u = fraction * this.options.vectorLength / 20,
       o = {
         start: 10 * u,
         center: 0,
         end: -10 * u
       }[this.options.rotationOrigin] || 0;

       // The stem and the arrow head. Draw the arrow first with rotation 0,
       // which is the arrow pointing down (vector from north to south).
       path = [
         'M', 0, 7 * u + o, // base of arrow
         'L', -1.5 * u, 7 * u + o,
         0, 10 * u + o,
         1.5 * u, 7 * u + o,
         0, 7 * u + o,
         0, -10 * u + o // top
       ];

       return path;
     }
   ```

   Regarding your question about defining start and end of a vector by two x, y values, you need to refactor entire series code, so that it won't use the `vectorLength` at all as like as scale, because you will define the points length. I suspect that will be very complex solution, so you can try to do it by yourself, and let me know about the results.
4. In order to make it works, you need to recalculate and update `vectorLength` of your vector series inside of `chart.events.selection` handler. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/nh7b6qx9/

Comment: 1. & 2. thanks for this example that helps for understanding extending highcharts! In Both fiddles you overwrite the translate method, is this necessary? it looks just like the vector base implementation to me.

3. For now i'm using a sparse line chart to draw the 'vectors'. Thus, there are now arrow heads but that is fine at the moment and i'm able to define start and end of the vector. I'll probably look into drawing arrowheads in line charts...

4. Thanks for the example. Any thoughts on resizing the background image? Could a temporary in memory image be set as background?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. It's only temporary code ;) Sorry for discrepancy. Regarding your question about the background, I answer very similar topic few days ago and I think that could be very helpful for you. Please take a look on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551560/how-to-insert-overlay-images-in-highmaps-or-highcharts-which-scale-with-the-ma

Comment: It helps in a way. Thanks. It looks like i'm not able to change the plot background in the event at all. But i can use a data series with a single point (as in your example) and use it as a background.

Comment: In which event are you trying to change the background and which way?

Comment: selection event. https://jsfiddle.net/pg7wfhLv/16/ 
i tried multiple things: changing plotBackgroundImage url of chart, changing visibility, adding css class (with visibility hidden), ...