# How to insert overlay images in HighMaps (or HighCharts) which scale with the map

Tags: javascript, css, image, highcharts

I would like to overlay images on top of a map (map features) and found that HighMaps/HighCharts has two options - but neither of these are suitable. I was wondering if there are any other options?

Option 1: Embed an image using renderer.image - the problem is that the image is disconnected from the map so doesn't scale with it.

Option 2: Embed image as map symbols - the problem is that these auto-scale, i.e. as you zoom into the map (map becomes larger), the icons become smaller. They should stay the same scale and stay in the same place, as if they are part of the map itself - is that possible?

Another issue is that I want to insert many small images. The easiest would be to embed them as one large image on top of the map, with the area around the small images transparent so you can see the map underneath. However, the issue is that it blocks the mouse cursor from hovering over the map areas underneath. Maybe this can be corrected via CSS?

Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mappoint` series to add point by latitude and longitude, then change its `marker.symbol` value to any `url()`, and on every `selection` chart event, change the size and position of the image by calculating appropriate current scale.
I prepared an example and if you would have some questions about the code and how it works, please let me know.

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/vbou6sga/

Comment: Thanks very much. I created a fork which includes map navigation, but the image still shrinks when zooming in - https://jsfiddle.net/ep592zg4/. What I hope to achieve is that the image scales up when the map scales up, as if it is part of (stuck onto) the map, rather than resizing independently, is that possible?

Comment: In order to change that, you need to make `wrap()` on `Chart.zoomMap` function, which will do exactly the same things with image. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ncf4Lbe0/

Comment: That works great thanks. Would you by chance know how to de-activate the rollover, so it rollovers the map area behind the image? Many thanks!

Comment: Could you explain me more precisely what you mean?

Comment: When there is underlying data e.g. in this fork - https://jsfiddle.net/vdLozp9b/ - the image blocks mouse-over. I am trying to get the mouse over the country (Poland in this case) when the mouse is over the image, so it should ignore the image overlay. Thanks

Comment: Actually, you just need to disable all events on the `<image>` element of `series-1`, what you can achieve by this code: `.highcharts-series-1 > image {
  pointer-events: none;
}`. Now it's working well, here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/cjhgt23p/1/